# Is this a good way to publish? Is it correct to do it this way?

Tags: maven, gradle, build.gradle, publish

I am trying to publish multiple artifacts to Artifactory and have come up with the below logic. Is this ideal or can this be done in a better way? I will eventually be retrieving it using a combination of classifier and extension.

Note: I have not tried this yet due to limited infra resources.

```
publishing.publications {
  samplePublish(MavenPublication) {
        artifact("${projectDir}/dir1/dir2/file1.json") {
            classifier "filefoo"
            extension "json"
        }
        artifact("${projectDir}/dir1/dir3/file2.json") {
            classifier "filefoo"
            extension "json"
        }
        artifact("${projectDir}/dir1/dir4/file3.json") {
            classifier "filefoo"
            extension "json"
        }
        artifact("${projectDir}/dir1/dir5/file4.json") {
            classifier "filefoo"
            extension "json"
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried with a single block of artifact() and that works as expected (as below)

```
publishing.publications {
  samplePublish(MavenPublication) {
        artifact("${projectDir}/dir1/dir2/file1.json") {
            classifier "filefoo"
            extension "json"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I did a workaround (answered below). However, I'd be happy to see what solution the community offers.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so after some trial and error, I realized that publishing artifacts that have the same classifier and extension did not work. Instead, I followed an alternate approach to tar.gz all the necessary artifacts and then handle them downstream.

If someone else has a better solution, I'd be happy to implement it.